# How to get time printed in IST?

Tags: java, datetime

I can get the time as well as the timezone currently, but it is always printed in

```
Wed May 23 11:01:08 GMT+05:30 2012
```

As TimeZone I am getting `GMT+05:30`. instead of this, I want to print `IST`

I tried

```
 SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z");
```

but still, I am getting `GMT+05:30`

```
TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.SHORT); is also givine me GMT+05:30
```

There are various things I tried but did not get the desired output. I have used `Calender` but still unable to print `IST`.

Can anyone please let me know how to print `IST` in Time (even I don't want to print `Indian standard time`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't shown where you're actually *using* the `SimpleDateFormat`. Here's a short but complete example which *does* show IST:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z");
        Date date = new Date();
        // TODO: Avoid using the abbreviations when fetching time zones.
        // Use the full Olson zone ID instead.
        sd.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
        System.out.println(sd.format(date));
   }
}
```

Output on my machine:

```
2012.05.23 AD at 11:18:08 IST
```

Note that if `TimeZone.getDefault()` isn't showing "IST" then the issue may be:

- That the system can't actually identify your system time zone
- That your Java installation doesn't have full time zone information regarding i18n

Which version of Java are you using, and on what platform?

Comment: one more problem is " i dont want to fix IST here. It can be EDT or something else. how can i do that?

Comment: @rock: You use `TimeZone.getTimeZone` to fetch a `TimeZone`. As per my comment though, you should use Olson time zone IDs ("Europe/London" etc) instead of abbreviations if possible - the abbreviations are ambiguous.

Comment: while running this in computer it is printing IST at the end. But not in mobile device

Comment: @AnbarasuChinna: Without more information, I'm afraid we're unlikely to be able to help you. I suggest you ask a new question with a lot more details.

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet. Your answer is really helpful. I tried the code mentioned but my timezone is MUT. It looks like `Timezone` class of Java doesn't understand MUT timezone. So it gives me date with GMT suffix. Could you please help me with that issue?

Comment: @RAS: I suggest you ask a new question with more details. (I don't even know what the MUT time zone is, and I suspect many others won't either.) I would strongly advise avoiding both `TimeZone` and `Date` though - use the `java.time` types instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet: OK.. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

## java.time

The accepted answer uses the legacy date-time and formatting API which was the correct thing to do in 2012. In March 2014, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) supplanted the legacy date-time API. Since then, it has been strongly recommended to switch to `java.time`, the modern date-time API.

Apart from staying away from the legacy date-time and formatting API, one should also avoid using two/three letter timezone IDs. Here is an extract from the official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html):

> #### *Three-letter time zone IDs*
>
> For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST")
> are also supported. However, **their use is deprecated** because the
> same abbreviation is often used for multiple time zones (for example,
> "CST" could be U.S. "Central Standard Time" and "China Standard
> Time"), and the Java platform can then only recognize one of them.

The time zone ID is typically represented as Region/City e.g. Asia/Kolkata. Check [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) for more information.

The modern date-time API provides a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class that holds the information about the time zone and zone offset. The best thing about this class is that it adjusts the zone offset automatically as per the [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

**Demo**:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var zoneId = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");

        // Current time in India
        var now = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId);
        System.out.println(now);

        // ###### Print the ZonedDateTime in custom formats ######

        var formatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String strDateTimeCustomFormat = now.format(formatter1);
        System.out.println(strDateTimeCustomFormat);

        var formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss VV", Locale.ENGLISH);
        strDateTimeCustomFormat = now.format(formatter2);
        System.out.println(strDateTimeCustomFormat);
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
2024-03-02T22:27:55.546343100+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
2024.03.02 AD at 22:27:55 IST
2024.03.02 AD at 22:27:55 Asia/Kolkata
```

#### [Online Demo](https://ideone.com/l2MczS)

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**

Comment: Good point on discouraging use of 3-letter time zones

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question. However, it may help with new Java data/time API, because other answers using the old one.

One can use the ZonedDateTime to print the data/time in requested format. Following example uses the pattern given in question.

```java
ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of(ZoneId.SHORT_IDS.get("IST"))).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z"))
```

You first create the Date/Time instance based on IST zone. Then, you call the format function with given pattern to print date/time in desired format.

It prints the result in IST:

```bash
jshell> ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of(ZoneId.SHORT_IDS.get("IST"))).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z"))
$10 ==> "2023.10.29 AD at 20:19:38 IST"
```

Comment: Thanks for the modern answer, it’s good to have. Over `ZoneId.of(ZoneId.SHORT_IDS.get("IST"))` I would prefer the simpler `ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")`. And I suspect that readers that want India Standard Time (IST) can figure out that Asia/Kolkata gives us this. Standard time zone IDs are like this, in the format *region/city*.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have a wrong timezone setting. The following code will print `2012.05.23 AD at 11:30:20 IST`

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z");
System.out.println(f.format(new Date()));
```

However, if I use `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30"));`

I'll get `2012.05.23 AD at 11:30:20 GMT+05:30`.

What comes in, comes out identical.